# Runtime Exec changing path

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I need to launch another Java program at runtime, this is my code

```
  try {
                                 String cmd2 = "java -jar c:\\test\\deploy\\framework_e_app.jar";

                                 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);  
                                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                                     new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
                                 String line = null;  
                                 while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                                         System.out.print("<STDOUT>");
                                     System.out.print(line);
                                     System.out.println("</STDOUT>");
                                 }  

                                 InputStream stderr = p.getErrorStream();
                                 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
                                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                                 String line2 = null;
                                 System.out.print("<STDERROR>");
                                 while ( (line2 = br.readLine()) != null)
                                     System.out.print(line2);
                                 System.out.println("</STDERROR>");

                         } catch (IOException e) {  
                             e.printStackTrace();  
                         }
```

This is the only way i got it working, but it is annoying because it search configuration files in the current path.

I tried using this as cmd2:

```
String[] cmd2 = new String[4];
cmd2[0] = "cmd";
cmd2[1] = "/C";
cmd2[2] = "cd test\\deploy";
cmd2[3] = "java -jar framework_e_app.jar";
```

**I couldn't get working the directory change.** What's the right syntax? (Im in a Windows environment, obviously).

Comment: isn't this windows way of doing this `cmd2[1] = "C:";` but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cd does not stick. each command is executed in a different process. use a form of exec that has the working directory like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29